# Mangled ANSI Color Codes in Log File

Tags: spring-boot, logging, encoding, logback, ansi-escape

I am trying to output logs with colour codes using `Logback` and `SpringBoot`. I am sure this has nothing to do with the two tools I am using. Just an encoding thing.

The format I am using in the pattern is:

```
%red(%date) %blue(%logger) [%highlight(%-5level)] [%yellow(%method)] [%green(%thread)]%cyan(: %msg%n%throwable)
```

When I open this in lets say Notepad++ or plain Notepad, all of the colours codes have garbled escape characters like `[39m` etc. A typical log line looks like this in the file:

```
[0;39m[31m2022-09-20 14:09:15,895[0;39m [34morg.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory[0;39m [[39mTRACE[0;39m] [[33mregisterScope[0;39m] [[32mmain[0;39m][36m: Registering scope 'restart' with implementation
```

In SpringBoot `application.yaml` I am using:

```
logging:
  charset:
    console: UTF-8
    file: UTF-8
```

Is there any way to get rid of this? Or do I have to use any specialised software for this? Would changing the encoding of the file help?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can help, but until more details are clear, I can add that this are linux shell console color codes, i.e. terminals will interpret this and output the according colors instead of printing the text in the foreground color. You can see that for example in the Linuxsubsystem by calling the command cat with the color option in the terminal. I guess what you see is the expected behavior.